# Pentaho cuts double values from Table Input

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a Problem that I could not fix up to now. When I do a "Select" at a Table-Input the double values are not returned completely and are always cut. Here are some examples:
15.0420 => 15 // 12.6000 => 12,6 // 4.1176 => 4,1 // 0.1123 => 0,1 // 0.0012 => 0

I seems like, that minimum two numbers are shown and max one number after the comma. However it is very important to get the right figures.
I use pentaho 6.1, and mariaDB 5.5.49.

Thanks for every help.

Best regards,
Dave

Comment: in table input step it will show the values directly what is coming from table.
if you doing some operation like a/b then you have to explicitly set the format for decimal point you want to display.

Comment: I do not do any operations. I just want to load the data and it is cutting the values like represented at the top. However I want to see the full numbers from the table-input and not the cutted values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I adjusted the configuration of the Default Number Format. Under "Edit->Edit the kettle.properties file", I set the "KETTLE_DEFAULT_NUMBER_FORMAT" with the format '#.####'. Now it is working!